# Empty windows in Apache Flink

Tags: java, apache-flink

I have a datastream with event time, is it possible to emit windows with no data in Apache Flink? For example with a tumbling window size of `15 minutes` it would be ideal if I could empty windows if they have no events in the time period of `[(0, 15), (15, 20), ...]` for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not possible. Flink's window operator only creates a window when the first event is added to it.

The reason for not emitting results for empty windows is, that windows are typically defined on a keyed stream (without keying a stream it is not possible to process the window in parallel). If Flink would emit records for empty windows on a keyed stream, it would need to emit a result for every possible key value. Since there are way too many possible keys, this is not possible.

Comment: I would think that depends on the use case, having an option for a job to 'emit for every key', or 'emit for every key that was seen in the last X time' may not be a bad idea.