# Can Flink count to zero?

Tags: count, apache-flink, flink-streaming, flink-sql

I have found examples for counting in Flink SQL, however I cannot seem to count to zero.

The obvious use case would be monitoring, where an action would need to be taken if an update is NOT received.

Here is what I tried so far:

```
select count(*) from emptysource
GROUP BY TUMBLE(PROCTIME(), INTERVAL '1' second)
```

When counting from the end of a topic that does not receive any messages, the count does not show zero. In fact, nothing seems to be produced by this job, though it does run succesfully.

I have not tried more complicated setups, where we would count per key.

I am primarily interested in Flink SQL, but if another solution in Flink would be needed that would be good to know as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that Flink currently doesn't support windows that have no elements, so Flink basically creates a window only after a first element for this window arrives. Some additional info can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54580982/empty-windows-in-apache-flink), even though the answer is for event time, but the rule for processing time is basically the same.

Possible workarounds depend on exact usecase but generally can be something like:

- Use keyed timers to emit periodical aggregations (this will only work if at leas one message arrives for key)
- Use dummy source just so that windows are created correctly (as described  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34326408/how-to-execute-functions-on-empty-windows-in-flink-streaming))

Comment: Thanks, I figured the dummy source approach would be one way to go but hoped there would be something more elegant. But sometimes hearing no is also a good answer ;-)